# MILP constraints with truth table

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, integer-programming, constraints, mixed-integer-programming

I have two decision variables, $SL_i$ = the amount I'm contributing to my student loan debt in month i, and $fiftySL_i$ = 1 if I contribute at least \$50 over the minimum payment (so contribute $350) in month i.

I've set up the truth table below, and want to eliminate the second and third scenarios. I've only used truth tables for strictly binary variables, so I'm not sure how to do this.

\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
SL_i& fiftySL_i   \\ \hline
 < 350& 0 \\ \hline
 < 350&  1\\ \hline
 \ge 350& 0 \\ \hline
\ge 350& 1\end{array}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\begin{align} & 350 \cdot \delta \le x \le 349.99 + \delta\cdot (U-349.99)\\
&\delta \in \{0,1\}\\
& 0 \le x \le U
\end{align} $$

Comment: So is x the same thing as my $SL_i$ variable and the delta the same thing as my $PSL_i$? And can you clarify what the U value means?

Comment: I was hoping that would be self-evident. $U$ is an upper bound on $x$ as indicated by $0 \le x \le U$.

Comment: That's what I figured. Just wanted to make sure I was understanding your answer. Thank you!